# Ugly fonts in Mozilla/Chrome

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

I came from Windows  and just found one bad thing in Ubuntu - Font is **absolutely hard for read and ugly.**

Look at this to see what I mean:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0895jgi88d

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d15jgi9cb

What font do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liberation Sans for everything except fixed width. I use monospace for fixed width. Xubuntu x64. I'm grateful that Chrome renders fonts so well in Xubuntu. I would agree that in most other distros that I've tried except Elementary and Lubuntu font rendering in 64bit Chrome is sub-par. It's just as bad in 64bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Which font is displayed is determined by the `css` property `font-family`, it will list some options to match with browser's fonts to display. The browser's fonts are from system, in the `usr/share/fonts` directory, also you can run `fc-list` to show all available fonts.

The Ubuntu default fonts are ugly (IMO) so I copied the Mac fonts and put them in `/usr/share/fonts/` directory, then Firefox/Chrome could pick these fonts from Mac to display, which give me a much better experience.

e.g. assume you have one font from San Francisco fonts which is `SFNSText.ttf`, to use it in Ubuntu, run:

```
$ sudo cp SFNSText.ttf /usr/share/fonts
$ fc-cache -v -f
```

Then you will see this font is available in your browser font settings.